# KeePass, GoogleSync: "Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response"

Tags: google-drive-api, keepass

When using KeePass with the GoogleSync plugin (to sync the keypass db with Google Drive), I somehow messed up my config and received this message on every sync attempt:

`Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response`

I think what I actually did was try to switch my Google API credentials (from one API key to another)

Answer (score 0):

The user config saves a Google auth key. In my case I changed the API credentials I wanted to use, but it could become corrupted in other ways and there doesn't seem to be a mechanism in KeePass/GoogleSync to rectify it.

1. Exit KeePass
2. Delete (or backup to a different name) the file `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Dominik_Reichl\KeePass[...]\[version]\user.config`
3. Restart KeePass and it'll regenerate it with the correct config

Found my reference here:

http://sourceforge.net/p/kp-googlesync/discussion/general/thread/5dc763ba/